ADMM where finding minimum of Lagragian is hard
I am trying to use ADMM for a distributed/federated optimisation problem of the form
$$\min_{x, x_{1} x_{2}, ..., x_{n}}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}f_{i}(x_{i}) + \lambda\|x - x_{i}\|^{2}$$
$$s.t. \hspace{2mm} x = x_{i} \hspace{2mm} \forall i$$
If $\alpha_{i}$ denotes the dual variable for the $i^{th}$ constraint equation, then
The ADMM update will split this into three steps:
$$\begin{align*}
x_{i}^{t + 1} = argmin_{w}\{f_{i}(w) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\|x^{t} - w\|^{2} + \langle\alpha_{i}^{t}, x^{t} - w\rangle\} \hspace{4mm}: \text{Local variable update }\forall i\\
x^{t+1} = argmin_{w}\{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}f_{i}(x_{i}^{t + 1}) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\|w - x_{i}^{t + 1}\|^{2} + \langle\alpha_{i}^{t}, w - x_{i}^{t + 1}\rangle\} \hspace{4mm}: \text{Global variable update}\\
\alpha_{i}^{t + 1} = \alpha_{i}^{t} + \lambda(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x^{t + 1} - x_{i}^{t + 1}) \hspace{4mm} \text{Dual ascent/dual variable update}
\end{align*}$$
However, in my case, the very first step seems difficult to perform; obtaining the unconstrained local optimum at each step is not possible. The local functions are all infinitely differentiable, possibly non-convex, are $\beta$-smooth. but very complex (Deep Neural Networks) and expensive to compute.
Is there some way to perform a cheap/inexpensive ADMM where I do not need to compute the optimum at each step for the local variables? I was thinking of doing a few steps of gradient descent for each local objective, and then proceeding to the global variable update.
I would appreciate any literature references or suggestions from the community.
Thank you very much!
